# How can i switch PS4 Trophies to Offline Mode?

Tags: achievements, ps4

I was testing out my PS4 on Christmas with Knack, when i tried to view my trophies it wouldn't show me any unless i was online.

I remember this happening with the PS3 when they changed how Trophies worked and i had to switch them from Online Mode to Offline Mode to view them without a net connection. i also know that on my PSVita i could view my PS3 Trophies as well but only in Online Mode so i'm assuming the PS4 is using a similar system to what the Vita used for trophies since you can view PS3 and Vita Trophies as well.

Thing is, it was ages ago i did the mode switch on my PS3 and the Vita it's like a separate tab at the top which doesn't work if your not online. i can't remember what setting i had to alter on my PS3 and i can't seem to find anything option like that on the PS4.

So i am wondering How can i switch PS4 Trophies to Offline Mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do it (at least for now). You are [required to be online](http://www.polygon.com/2013/11/14/5103898/ps4-what-you-cant-do-offline) to view trophies. Quote:

> The PlayStation 4 will not allow users to look at their Trophies or
>   Friends lists when the console is offline, Polygon has learned using a
>   retail unit received for review purposes.
>
> The PS4 still doesn't sync Trophies in the background — every time you
>   load up your list of virtual accomplishments, the console takes a
>   moment to sync with Sony's servers. Perhaps because of that, you can't
>   view your Trophies list if you're not connected to the internet. On
>   PS3, you can scroll through your Trophies whenever you want, and you
>   can sync them the next time you're online. You can definitely earn
>   Trophies while playing PS4 games offline, but if you try to look at
>   your list when you've disabled the console's internet connection,
>   you'll get the following error message: "[Connect to the Internet] is turned off.
>   (NW-31484-0)"